# Set color for half of the star

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

How can I set a color only for half of the star? Like the image below?

[image]

```
    <span className={"star"}>
     ★
    </span>
```

Comment: You can't. You're going to need another dedicated icon for that.

Comment: If you dont have dedicated icon you can create one more div with star and fix the width as 50% and with position hover over the current one. This is not a good solution. Just find dedicated icon please.

Comment: @Santosh good point. I suppose if you're that desperate you could go full-send with `background-clip: text;` and a gradient, but I digress... :)

Comment: Or check this codepen found it after google. https://codepen.io/FredGenkin/pen/eaXYGV

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  font-size: 60px;
}


.half {
  display: inline-flex;
}

  .half > div:first-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 27px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #f97d00;
}   
  .half > div:last-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left:-27px;
}
 <span class='half'><div>★</div><div>★</div>
```